# c++ dynamic size of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have got a small problem with 1D array in c++. I have got a function line this:

```
void func(int (&array)[???])
{
    // some math here;

    "for" loop {
        array[i] = something;
    }
}
```

I call the functions somewhere in the code, and before I made math I'm not able to know dimension of the array. The array goes to the function as a reference!, because I need it in the main() function. How I can allocate array like this?, so array with ?? dimension goes to the function as reference then I have to put the dimension and write to it some values.

Comment: Really your question is a bit unclear. Is your problem allocation, access or how to pass an array to a function? Please show some actual code that illustrates your problem, or describe what you actually want to do.

Comment: An array of references is an unusual beast: you probably don't want to use references like that anyhow.

Comment: @Eamon: You can't have an array of references, the above code is a reference to an array.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne: I really think this is the best way to really give `func` an array and not a bare pointer that you will use like an array.

Comment: Ah right, I misread the declaration as the (invalid) `int &*arr` rather than the unusual but valid `int *&arr`.  I've never given `int&*arr` any thought - interesting to note that it is fortunately not merely a bad idea, but invalid too :-).  After all, you can to something fairly equivalent via the (equally unwise) `struct intRef { int & ref; intRef(int& ref):ref(ref){}};   void func(intRef * array) {}` - so there's nothing *fundamentally* problematic with a pointer to a reference, it's just... unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a pointer, not a reference:

```
void func(int *a, int N);
```

Or, easier, use a vector:

```
void func(std::vector<int> &a);
```

Vectors can be allocated by simply saying

```
std::vector<int> a(10);
```

The number of elements can be retrieved using `a.size()`.

Answer (score 14):

Since you're using C++, why not use a `std::vector<>` instead?

Comment: Additional +1 for vector, I use them all the time anytime I dont how how big "something" is going to be.

Comment: Do you think that answer is any helpful to a beginner?

Comment: @Dave: yes it is, it helps him understand that using "array"s in c++ can be done better, especially in these simple situations.

Comment: I hope I'm not going to insult nykon if I say that concluding from his question I think he didn't grasp the concept of arrays and pointers yet. This makes him being able to read api documentation unlikely. It's even questionable if a C++ beginner is able to conclude the existence of the standard template library from the snippet "std::vector<>"

Answer (score 10):

Other have mentioned that you should use `std::vector` in C++ and they are right.

But you can make your code work by making `func` a function template.

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void func(T (&array)[N])
{
    // some math here;

    "for" loop {
        array[i] = something;
    }
}
```

Comment: The template function way is a prime example of: "how to implement functionality already present in the Standard Library"...

Comment: @rubenvb: What do you think is being "implemented" here?

Comment: I agree with these "you should use a vector"; OK; but this answer provide a way to solve and understand the main question of the OP...

Comment: @Roger, @Cedric: I wasn't criticizing the quality of the answer, it's quite valid, but it kind of circumvents/avoids the presence of `std::vector::size()` in my view of things.

Answer (score 5):

If the array you pass to `func` is a stack array, and not a pointer, you can retain its size by using a function template:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
void func(T(&array)[N])
{
    size_t array_length = N; // or just use N directly
}

int main() 
{
    int array[4];
    func(array);
}
```

That said, as others have already pointed out, `std::vector` is probably the best solution here.

Comment: but unnecessary, because inside of func you got the template-parameter N which contains the same information (as a compile time constant).

Answer (score 0):

As well as vector which has been suggested you could possibly use valarray which is also part of STL and is intended specificially to handle mathematical collections.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to realize, is that arrays are pointers. A definition like `int array[5]` will allocate space for 5 integers on the stack and `array` will be the address of the first value. Thus, to access the first value in the array, you can write

`array[0]` or `*array` (which is the same as `*(array + 0)`)

In the same way to retrieve the address of the third element, you can write

`&array[2]` or `array + 2`

Since arrays are pointers, you don't have to worry about the runtime size of your array if you would like to pass it to a function, simply pass it as a pointer:
`void func(int *array)
{
    int size;
    //compute size of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        //do whatever you want with array[i]
    }
}`