# How do I find the length of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a way to find how many values an array has?  Detecting whether or not I've reached the end of an array would also work.

Comment: Where is the array coming from? Usually functions that take arrays also take a length parameter to deal with this problem.

Comment: Well, I'm making a "mad libs" program that has an array with all the text, as well as the locations of nouns/verbs that the user has to fill in.  I'd like to use a function to run through the entire array, replacing the "[noun]" and "[verb]" values with text entered by the user.

Comment: Please note that in C arrays are not objects or structures. As such, they have no length parameter stored anywhere by default. If you want to work with them as objects in C++, use C++ objects std::vector, or std::array of C++11 if you can. If you have to use pointers, always pass length of array as second parameter to every function that works with it.

Comment: If you're using C++20, then I have added answer for that as well. It could be missed easily as there are so many answers here.

Comment: [std::size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

Answer (score 650, accepted):

If you mean a C-style array, then you can do something like:

```
int a[7];
std::cout << "Length of array = " << (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)) << std::endl;
```

This doesn't work on pointers (i.e. it **won't work for either of the following**):

```
int *p = new int[7];
std::cout << "Length of array = " << (sizeof(p)/sizeof(*p)) << std::endl;
```

or:

```
void func(int *p)
{
    std::cout << "Length of array = " << (sizeof(p)/sizeof(*p)) << std::endl;
}

int a[7];
func(a);
```

In C++, if you want this kind of behavior, then you should be using a container class; probably [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: It also doesn't work if you pass the array to a different function and try to do it there :)

Comment: @San : In that case create a [`function template`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076664/c-dynamic-size-of-the-array/4076705#4076705)

Comment: @San Jacinto: No, this works (on *arrays*) no matter what function you are in. Passing an array of variable length to a function as a parameter, however, is impossible (it decays into a pointer) - but if you pass an array inside a struct, then this works as expected.

Comment: Is there an easier way in C++11?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth also if you passed the array by value to another function and tried it there, it won't work, right? The question is why

Comment: @A_Matar - You can't pass an array by value in C or C++.

Comment: @Dineshkumar: it does work in C++.  But in C++, you shouldn't *need* to do this.

Comment: Can someone explain what sizeof(p) and sizeof(*p) does?

Comment: @larryk: in what context? For a start, **p won't even compile for my code examples.

Comment: Why not sizeof(a) / sizeof(int) ?

Comment: The compiler errors regarding attempts to pass an array can be a little misleading, because the offending line would report `no matching function for call to 'foo(int [2])'` (types are listed verbatim, not decayed/etc.) and then cite `couldn't deduce template parameter 'N'` as the reason for substitution failure. Just putting it out there. Oh, and I should mention `int[] myArray = {0, 1}; foo<2>(myArray);` **compiles and runs correctly**, one rare exception (or rather nuance) to the rule. (C++11)

Comment: _"because the above works for any type"_ It certainly doesn't. IMO the template solution should be much more prominent (read: included at all) in an accepted answer of this score! :)

Comment: Does `*( (&p + 1) - p )/sizeof(*p)` work for the pointer case? (It's good for the array case.)

Answer (score 188):

As others have said, you can use the `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)`, but this will give you the wrong answer for pointer types that aren't arrays.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

This has the nice property of failing to compile for non-array types (Visual Studio has [`_countof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx) which does this). The [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) makes this a compile time expression so it doesn't have any drawbacks over the macro (at least none I know of).

You can also consider using `std::array` from C++11, which exposes its length with no overhead over a native C array.

**C++17** has [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) in the `<iterator>` header which does the same and works for STL containers too (thanks to [@Jon C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48543672/3848)).

Comment: I get two errors when compiling (I'm not even trying to use it): 
error C2265: '<Unknown>' : reference to a zero-sized array is illegal 
error C2266: '<Unknown>' : reference to a non-constant bounded array is illegal 
What's the problem?

Comment: @jimifiki can you supply a [IDEone](http://ideone.com) link or code sample so I can see? Either that or you can ask a question on SO since this code is well known to work ([sample](http://ideone.com/o00cAk))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482109/getting-the-length-of-an-array-compiler-errors

Comment: Maybe it's too late, but I'm quite confused about the parameter syntax `T (&)[N]`. Could someone provide a hint to Google that up?

Comment: @yau it's how you write a _reference to an array_, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10008405/3848). My version looks a bit different since I've left out the parameter's name since the parameter isn't used, only its type is needed. With a name it would be `T(arg&)[N]`.

Comment: Thanks Motti! The left out parameter name was already clear to me. But unbelievable that I apparently had no use of _refs/pointers to arrays_ ever before. And probably won't in the future, as such arrays are dying out even more.

Comment: Why is your template soln not in the std lib???? I guess they assume that nobody uses arrays anymore now that there is std::vector and std::array????

Comment: The old way of doing it in C++03 is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2037878/1667513), which is useful if you don't have `constexpr` and need the compile time constant.

Comment: If use C++11 is not std::extent a better solution???? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent

Comment: @IsaacPascual I wasn't familiar with `extent`, looking at it now there two characteristics with it that make it less useful than the function above (for this usecase). (1) It returns zero for pointers (rather than a compilation error). (2) It requires a type parameter so in order to check a variable you would have to do `decltype`

Answer (score 128):

While this is an old question, it's worth updating the answer to C++17.  In the standard library there is now the templated function [`std::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), which returns the number of elements in both a std container or a C-style array.  For example:

```
#include <iterator>

uint32_t data[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
auto dataSize = std::size(data);
// dataSize == 4
```

Comment: and with C++20, `std::ssize()` to get the `std::size()` of any range as a signed integer, useful for avoiding wrapping horror in loops, verbose casts to avoid the former, etc.

Comment: You should note that this doesn't work for arrays passed into a function, you need to do it in the block where the array is defined and pass it as an additional parameter to the function.

Answer (score 113):

Doing `sizeof myArray` will get you the total number of bytes allocated for that array. You can then find out the number of elements in the array by dividing by the size of one element in the array: `sizeof myArray[0]`

So, you get something like:

```
size_t LengthOfArray = sizeof myArray / sizeof myArray[0];
```

Since `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, the result `LengthOfArray` will also be of this type.

Comment: This is a very simple and easy solution to overcome what seems to be an age old problem.

Comment: Doesn't work for C++ "new" arrays held by a pointer. You get the size of the pointer (4 bytes) or the size of its first element if you dereference it.

Comment: @DragonLord yes, although anyone declaring the size of the array using the keyword new will already know the size of the array at runtime, so there's no need to use the sizeof operator to find the size of the array in that case. I'm sure you know that. This is just for the benefit of anyone who doesn't.

Comment: @surega It won't crash

Answer (score 67):

> Is there a way to find how many values an array has?

Yes!

Try `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`

> Detecting whether or not I've reached the end of an array would also work.

I dont see any way for this unless your array is an array of characters (i.e string).

P.S : In C++ always use `std::vector`. There are several inbuilt functions and an extended functionality.

Comment: This wouldn't work for variable individual array sizes

Comment: +1 for vectors. There's very few strong cases to be using the old-style C++ arrays any more. Unless the size of the array is never going to change, but even then, you should use the array container class instead. It's better to use a container class like vector for dynamic array storage. The pros of using container classes far outweigh the cons of having to manage your own memory.

Comment: @MartynShutt When you are cache-bound, like in gamedev, you can't afford to use a vector sometimes.

Comment: If an array has 0 elements, is array[0] legal then?

Comment: @mercury0114 0 length arrays are illegal in C++. And even if they weren't, you're still allowed to evaluate the `sizeof` operator on `array[0]`, since it doesn't actually evaluate it at runtime, just finds the type of it at compile time to get the size.

Answer (score 36):

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;
    int arr[] = {2, 7, 1, 111};
    auto array_length = end(arr) - begin(arr);
    cout << "Length of array: " << array_length << endl;
}
```

Comment: I believe this one only works for local variables that are on the stack.

Comment: This is the best answer. @DragonLord, it works for member vars as well. See http://cpp.sh/92xvv.

Answer (score 33):

`std::vector` has a method `size()` which returns the number of elements in the vector.

(Yes, this is tongue-in-cheek answer)

Comment: Tongue in cheek it may be, but it's almost certainly the right approach.

Comment: why do you say it's tongue in cheek?  to me (a c++ newbie) it just seems like the right answer.

Comment: @dbliss It's tongue-in-cheek because the OP asked about the length of an *array* and eq- tells them how to get the length of a *vector*, which is a different thing in C++. However, it's correct at a deeper level because [if you need to get the length at run time, a vector is a much better choice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15079057/243712).

Comment: You could also use std::list or some other containers I believe.

Comment: What's especially great about this answer is that you can initialize a vector or list with an array literal.

Answer (score 33):

This is pretty much old and legendary question and there are already many amazing answers out there. But with time there are new functionalities being added to the languages, so we need to keep on updating things as per new features available.

I just noticed any one hasn't mentioned about C++20 yet. So thought to write answer.

### C++20

In C++20, there is a new better way added to the standard library for finding the length of array i.e. `std:ssize()`. This function returns a `signed value`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << std::ssize(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

### C++17

In C++17 there was a better way (at that time) for the same which is `std::size()` defined in `iterator`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // required for std::size

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << "Size is " << std::size(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. This method works for `vector` as well.

### Old

This traditional approach is already mentioned in many other answers.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Just FYI, if you wonder why this approach *doesn't work when array is passed to another function*. The reason is,

An array is not passed by value in C++, instead the pointer to array is passed. As in some cases passing the whole arrays can be expensive operation. You can test this by passing the array to some function and make some changes to array there and then print the array in main again. You'll get updated results.

And as you would already know, the `sizeof()` function gives the number of bytes, so in other function it'll return the number of bytes allocated for the pointer rather than the whole array. So this approach doesn't work.

But I'm sure you can find a good way to do this, as per your requirement.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 29):

Since C++11, some new templates are introduced to help reduce the pain when dealing with array length. All of them are defined in header `<type_traits>`.

- [`std::rank<T>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank)

  If `T` is an array type, provides the member constant value equal to the number of dimensions of the array. For any other type, value is 0.
- [`std::extent<T, N>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent)

  If `T` is an array type, provides the member constant value equal to the number of elements along the `N`th dimension of the array, if `N` is in [0, `std::rank<T>::value`). For any other type, or if `T` is array of unknown bound along its first dimension and `N` is 0, value is 0.
- [`std::remove_extent<T>::type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_extent)

  If `T` is an array of some type `X`, provides the member typedef type equal to `X`, otherwise type is `T`. Note that if `T` is a multidimensional array, only the first dimension is removed.
- [`std::remove_all_extents<T>::type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_all_extents)

  If `T` is a multidimensional array of some type `X`, provides the member typedef type equal to `X`, otherwise type is `T`.

To get the length on any dimension of a multidimential array, `decltype` could be used to combine with `std::extent`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> // std::remove_extent std::remove_all_extents std::rank std::extent

template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t length(T(&)[N]) { return N; }

template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t length2(T(&arr)[N]) { return sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); }

int main()
{
    int a[5][4][3]{{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}, { }, {{7,8,9}}};

    // New way
    constexpr auto l1 = std::extent<decltype(a)>::value;     // 5
    constexpr auto l2 = std::extent<decltype(a), 1>::value;  // 4
    constexpr auto l3 = std::extent<decltype(a), 2>::value;  // 3
    constexpr auto l4 = std::extent<decltype(a), 3>::value;  // 0

    // Mixed way
    constexpr auto la = length(a);
    //constexpr auto lpa = length(*a);  // compile error
    //auto lpa = length(*a);  // get at runtime
    std::remove_extent<decltype(a)>::type pa;  // get at compile time
    //std::remove_reference<decltype(*a)>::type pa;  // same as above
    constexpr auto lpa = length(pa);
    std::cout << la << ' ' << lpa << '\n';

    // Old way
    constexpr auto la2 = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
    constexpr auto lpa2 = sizeof(*a) / sizeof(**a);
    std::cout << la2 << ' ' << lpa2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

BTY, to get the total number of elements in a multidimentional array:

```
constexpr auto l = sizeof(a) / sizeof(std::remove_all_extents<decltype(a)>::type);
```

Or put it in a function template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>     

template<class T>
constexpr size_t len(T &a)
{
    return sizeof(a) / sizeof(typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type);
}

int main()
{
    int a[5][4][3]{{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}, { }, {{7,8,9}}};
    constexpr auto ttt = len(a);
    int i;
    std::cout << ttt << ' ' << len(i) << '\n';     
    return 0;
}
```

More examples of how to use them could be found by following the links.

Answer (score 19):

There's also the TR1/C++11/C++17 way (see it <kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c53173dcc0c4286)</kbd>):

```
const std::string s[3] = { "1"s, "2"s, "3"s };
constexpr auto n       = std::extent<   decltype(s) >::value; // From <type_traits>
constexpr auto n2      = std::extent_v< decltype(s) >;        // C++17 shorthand

const auto     a    = std::array{ "1"s, "2"s, "3"s };   // C++17 class template arg deduction -- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction
constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size_v< decltype(a) >;

std::cout << n << " " << n2 << " " << size << "\n"; // Prints 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using the built in array function aka:

```
 int x[3] = {0, 1, 2};
```

you should use the array class and the array template. Try:

```
#include <array>
array<type_of_the_array, number_of_elements_in_the_array> Name_of_Array = {};
```

So now if you want to find the length of the array, all you have to do is using the size function in the array class.

```
Name_of_Array.size();
```

and that should return the length of elements in the array.

Answer (score 8):

**ANSWER**:

```
int number_of_elements = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

**EXPLANATION**:

Since the compiler sets a specific size chunk of memory aside for each type of data, and an array is simply a group of those, you simply divide the size of the array by the size of the data type. If I have an array of 30 strings, my system sets aside 24 bytes for each element(string) of the array. At 30 elements, that's a total of 720 bytes. 720/24 == 30 elements. The small, tight algorithm for that is:

`int number_of_elements = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` which equates to

`number_of_elements = 720/24`

Note that you don't need to know what data type the array is, even if it's a custom data type.

Comment: No need for this antiquated and error prone approach in 2019. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59109106/560648 Also it's just a dupe of existing answers.

Comment: It is, however, simple, eloquent, quick, low-demand, platform independent and eliminates the need to include vector or pointers. As far as duping other answers, there seems to be only one other answer with the same algorithm, and that one gives no explanation as to the underlying mechanics of the problem as my answer does. I respectfully suggest that, rather than being error-prone, it is quite robust.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, using the std::array class to declare an array, one can easily find the size of an array and also the last element.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
int main()
{
    std::array<int,3> arr;

    //To find the size of the array
    std::cout<<arr.size()<<std::endl;

    //Accessing the last element
    auto it=arr.end();
    std::cout<<arr.back()<<"\t"<<arr[arr.size()-1]<<"\t"<<*(--it);

    return 0;
}
```

---

In fact, array class has a whole lot of other functions which let us use array a standard container.
[Reference 1 to C++ std::array class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/?kw=array)
[Reference 2 to std::array class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)
The examples in the references are helpful.

Comment: Nice; I see you got many skills; and ... great approach. I think should write more answers to such famous questions myself, too ;-)

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof(array_name)` gives the size of whole array and `sizeof(int)` gives the size of the data type of every array element.

So dividing the size of the whole array by the size of a single element of the array gives the **length** of the array.

```
 int array_name[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
 int length = sizeof(array_name)/sizeof(int);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 6):

You have a bunch of options to be used to get a C array size.

**int myArray[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7};**

`1) sizeof(<array>) / sizeof(<type>):`

```
std::cout << "Size:" << sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(int) << std::endl;
```

`2) sizeof(<array>) / sizeof(*<array>):`

```
std::cout << "Size:" << sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(*myArray) << std::endl;
```

`3) sizeof(<array>) / sizeof(<array>[<element>]):`

```
std::cout << "Size:" << sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can find the length of an Array by following:

```
int  arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; 
int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr; 
cout << "Number of elements in arr[] is "<< size; 
return 0;
```

Comment: Simplifies to  (&arr)[1] - arr;

Answer (score 3):

Here is one implementation of `ArraySize` from [Google Protobuf](http://osxr.org/android/source/external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h).

```
#define GOOGLE_ARRAYSIZE(a) \
  ((sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a))) / static_cast<size_t>(!(sizeof(a) % sizeof(*(a)))))

// test codes...
char* ptr[] = { "you", "are", "here" };
int testarr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
cout << GOOGLE_ARRAYSIZE(testarr) << endl;
cout << GOOGLE_ARRAYSIZE(ptr) << endl;
```

> ARRAYSIZE(arr) works by inspecting sizeof(arr) (the # of bytes in
>    the array) and sizeof(*(arr)) (the # of bytes in one array
>    element).  If the former is divisible by the latter, perhaps arr is
>    indeed an array, in which case the division result is the # of
>    elements in the array.  Otherwise, arr cannot possibly be an array,
>    and we generate a compiler error to prevent the code from
>    compiling.
>
> Since the size of bool is implementation-defined, we need to cast
>    !(sizeof(a) & sizeof(*(a))) to size_t in order to ensure the final
>    result has type size_t.
>
> This macro is not perfect as it wrongfully accepts certain
>    pointers, namely where the pointer size is divisible by the pointee
>    size.  Since all our code has to go through a 32-bit compiler,
>    where a pointer is 4 bytes, this means all pointers to a type whose
>    size is 3 or greater than 4 will be (righteously) rejected.

Comment: with an array of integer like this following : `int nombres[5] = { 9, 3 };` this function returns `5` instead of `2`.

Comment: `GOOGLE_ARRAYSIZE(new int8_t)` returns `8` on my test env, instead of raising error. Casted part seems redundant, not mentioning screaming C macro. `sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)` works way enough as legacy solution.

Answer (score 3):

A good solution that uses generics:

```
template <typename T,unsigned S>
inline unsigned arraysize(const T (&v)[S]) { return S; }
```

Then simply call `arraysize(_Array);` to get the length of the array.

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/33669/#msg181103)

Comment: @bobbogo Works with inline or constexpr, maybe you had inline off or it is optional? https://ideone.com/VxogJ4

Comment: @QentinUK  `constexpr` is the fix. `inline` is not. `constexpr` is pretty modern though. Are you sure your test program is not using another modern feature, where you can declare a local array whose length is given by a variable? Try it with two global arrays.

Answer (score 3):

For old g++ compiler, you can do this

```
template <class T, size_t N>
char (&helper(T (&)[N]))[N];

#define arraysize(array) (sizeof(helper(array)))

int main() {
    int a[10];
    std::cout << arraysize(a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Very portable amongst C++ versions, does not work with pointers, plus the answer is available at compile time

Answer (score 3):

For C++/CX (when writing e.g. UWP apps using C++ in Visual Studio) we can find the number  of values in an array by  simply using the `size()` function.

**Source Code:**

```
string myArray[] = { "Example1", "Example2", "Example3", "Example4" };
int size_of_array=size(myArray);
```

If you `cout` the `size_of_array` the output will be:

```
>>> 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, but just decided to create a counter variable and store the array size in position [0].  I deleted most of the code I had in the function but you'll see after exiting the loop, prime[0] is assigned the final value of 'a'. I tried using vectors but VS Express 2013 didn't like that very much.  Also make note that 'a' starts at one to avoid overwriting [0] and it's initialized in the beginning to avoid errors.  I'm no expert, just thought I'd share.

```
int prime[] = {0};
int primes(int x, int y){
    using namespace std; int a = 1;
    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++){prime[a] = i; a++; }
    prime[0] = a; return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  array<int,3> values;
  cout << "No. elements in valuea array: " << values.size() << " elements." << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(myints): " << sizeof(values) << endl;

}
```

and here is the reference : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/size/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sizeof() operator which is used for the same purpose.

see below the sample code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int arr[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60};
  int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  cout << "The size of the array is: " << arrSize;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I provide a tricky solution here:

You can always store `length` in the first element:

```
// malloc/new

arr[0] = length;
arr++;

// do anything. 
int len = *(arr-1);

free(--arr);
```

The cost is you must `--arr` when invoke `free`

Comment: That works only when `arr` is of a type compatible with `int` and the array is not longer than the maximum value of the type. E.g. Pascal strings are actually byte arrays using this trick; the maximum length of strings in Pascal is 255 characters.

Comment: I suppose one could reserve say 8 bytes at the beginning of each array and use an unsigned long if they wanted to store objects. I think a vector is probably easier. But definitely a good solution for embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 int arr[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60};
 int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
 cout << "The size of the array is: " << arrSize;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution is nearly identical to the accepted answer. Please add comments on that if you believe it require modification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::end(arr) - std::begin(arr)` method in C++11 and later.

It works with C-style arrays, uninitialized arrays, `std::array`, `std::vector` and I think other containers works.

**For example:**

```cpp
int arr`[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };

std::cout << std::end(nums) - std::begin(nums) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common reasons you would end up looking for this is because you want to pass an array to a function, and not have to pass another argument for its size.  You would also generally like the array size to be dynamic.  That array might contain objects, not primitives, and the objects maybe complex such that size_of() is a not safe option for calculating the count.

As others have suggested, consider using an std::vector or list, etc in instead of a primitive array.  On old compilers, however, you still wouldn't have the final solution you probably want by doing simply that though, because populating the container requires a bunch of ugly push_back() lines. If you're like me, want a single line solution with anonymous objects involved.

If you go with STL container alternative to a primitive array, this SO post may be of use to you for ways to initialize it:
[What is the easiest way to initialize a std::vector with hardcoded elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-initialize-a-stdvector-with-hardcoded-elements)

Here's a method that I'm using for this which will work universally across compilers and platforms:

Create a struct or class as container for your collection of objects.  Define an operator overload function for <<.

```
class MyObject;

struct MyObjectList
{
    std::list<MyObject> objects;
    MyObjectList& operator<<( const MyObject o )
    { 
        objects.push_back( o );
        return *this; 
    }
};
```

You can create functions which take your struct as a parameter, e.g.:

```
someFunc( MyObjectList &objects );
```

Then, you can call that function, like this:

```
someFunc( MyObjectList() << MyObject(1) <<  MyObject(2) <<  MyObject(3) );
```

That way, you can build and pass a dynamically sized collection of objects to a function in one single clean line!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the type together with sizeof, as `sizeof(array)/sizeof(char)`, suddenly gets corrupt if you change the type of the array.

In visual studio, you have the equivivalent if `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`.
You can simply type `_countof(array)`

Answer (score -1):

I personally would suggest (if you are unable to work with specialized functions for whatever reason) to first expand the arrays type compatibility past what you would normally use it as (if you were storing values ≥ 0:

```
unsigned int x[] -> int x[]
```

than you would make the array 1 element bigger than you need to make it. For the last element you would put some type that is included in the expanded type specifier but that you wouldn't normally use e.g. using the previous example the last element would be -1. This enables you (by using a for loop) to find the last element of an array.

Answer (score -2):

I think this will work:

```
for(int i=0;array[i];i++)
{
 //do_something
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Lets say you have an global array declared at the top of the page

```
int global[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

To find out how many elements are there (in c++) in the array type the following code:

```
sizeof(global) / 4;
```

The sizeof(NAME_OF_ARRAY) / 4 will give you back the number of elements for the given array name.

Comment: sizeof(int) is platform dependent. There is no guarantee that it will be 4 (though this is the most common case)

Comment: Than you for addition.

Comment: Magic numbers!!

Comment: Sorry but A. the size of an `int` depends on the platform, and B, this contributes absolutely *nothing* to the discussion.