# Getting the length of an array. Compiler errors.

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, compiler-errors, visual-c++-6

I've tried:

```
template <typename T,unsigned S> 
unsigned getArraySize(const T (&v)[S]) { return S; }
```

after Motti's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18078435/512225

but I've got this message:

error C2265: '' : reference to a zero-sized array is illegal

What's wrong with my compiler?

I gave a look at this page: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4b78bcef-4c33-42f1-a4c5-fb6f702ced0b/vs6-c-compile-error-using-getaddrinfo 
so I tried this solution:

```
template <typename T,unsigned S> 
unsigned getArraySize(const T v[S]) { return S; }
```

this compiles, but when I try to use it:

```
double myX[2] = {7,3};
std::cout << getArraySize(myX) << std::endl;
```

I get a compilation error:
error C2783: 'unsigned int __cdecl getArraySize(const T [])' : could not deduce template argument for 'S'

Beside changing the compiler, is there a workaround I can use to get the array's size?

Comment: Use `std::array`. What is the error when you do `getArraySize(myX)` with the first definition? The error implies a zero length array, but your array `myX` obviously has more than zero elements.

Comment: Can you post the code that is giving you C2265 for the first solution?

Comment: The first example should work... I literally copy/pasted it and ran it and it returned 2. What compiler do you have?

Comment: Did you try this on a more recent msvc compiler? vc6 is at least a decade old.

Comment: Your first version [should work](http://ideone.com/MfZ8OZ). Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: You might not pass a 'const T []', a 'const T [1]' should work.

Comment: @greatwolf More like 2 decades. 10 years ago, there was VS 2003.

Comment: @Rapptz my company is using VC6, I think std::array has recently been added to the standard library.

Comment: @Angew the first solution in an included header file gives the error (even if the template function is never called) i.e. there's no more code than these two lines

Comment: @greatwolf I'm pretty sure that on a more recent compiler it works, I'll try at home

Comment: @juanchopanza my example is short, self contained, correct (according to most compilers) but of course cannot compile (that's the reason why I ask a question, isn't it)? :-)

Comment: @jimifiki It would have been easier to rule out other errors if you had posted something like the demo linked from my last comment.

Comment: @jimifiki I guess the only answer here is "update to a more recent compiler, or at least to one which at least *pretends* to care about the standard." VC++6 was never one for following the standard, especially with templates. Can't really blame it, it was released in the same year as the first C++ standard, but really is *not* a C++ compiler.

Comment: @jimifiki If updating isn't an option for whatever reason, you'll just have to fallback to the old C method `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` as a workaround. But don't worry! Macros can help here! :D

Comment: These are my accepted answers 
-the only answer here is "update to a more recent compiler, 
-If updating isn't an option for whatever reason, you'll just have to fallback to the old C method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a limitation of VC6, have you tried other compilers?

Answer (score 1):

> but I've got this message:
>
> error C2265: '' : reference to a zero-sized array is illegal

Arrays with zero size are illegal in C++.
So this probably means you tried with an array of zero size.

> this compiles, but when I try to use it:

If you don't use it. Then the compiler is going to ignore a template (even if it has errors). This is because you can not always deduce if a template function is correct without knowing the types involved. So unless there is a call to a template function no error message will be generated.

> template <typename T,unsigned S>
>   unsigned getArraySize(const T v[S]) { return S; }

This fails because you are not allowed to pass arrays as parameters (you can only pass references to arrays).