# How to output size of rows and columns of matrixOpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  Mat image = imread("cupcake.jpg");
  int rows=image.rows; 
  cout<< rows<< endl;
  int cols=image.cols;
  cout<< cols<< endl;
  Point2f src_point[] = {Point2f(0,0),Point2f(cols-1,0),Point2f(0, rows-1)};

  cout << src_point[0].rows;
  cout << src_point[0].cols;
  */I have tried src_point.Size. (says Size is not a member of cv::Point2f) */
}
```

I am trying to input a manual grid for row and clumns display. In the first cout i have gotten the number of displays and rows but in the second cout of src_point i am unable to display the number of rows and columns of the new matrix.

I have searched around and i have stumbled upon some some codes that will output pixel values by assigning pointer to them.

What i need is to get size of rows and cols of the new src_point

Comment: src_point is not a matrix (and not a cv::Mat), but a plain old 1D c-style array.

Comment: Therefore should work like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
Mat image = imread("/home/winowa/Desktop/Intern101/cupcake.jpg");
int rows = image.rows;
int cols =image.cols;

cout<< "==============ImageRows&Cols"<<endl;
cout<<image.rows<<endl;
cout<<image.cols<<endl;
cout<<image.type()<<endl;

Mat src_points;
cout<< "==============src_point"<<endl;
src_points.create(498, 450, CV_32FC1);
cout << src_points.rows <<endl;
cout << src_points.cols <<endl;
cout << src_points.type() <<endl;


Point2f srcPoint[3];
Point2f dstPoint[3];

//srcPoint2[20] = Point2f(0,0),(image.cols -1,0),(0,image,rows-1);
srcPoint[0] = Point2f(0,0);
srcPoint[1] = Point2f(image.cols -1,0);
srcPoint[2] = Point2f(0,image.rows -1);

cout<< "==============src_point Point2f"<<endl;
//cout<< srcPoint[0][1][2] << endl;
cout<< srcPoint[0] << endl;
cout<< srcPoint[1] << endl;
cout<< srcPoint[2] << endl;

cout<< "==============dst_point"<<endl;
Mat dst_points;
dst_points.create(498,450,CV_32FC1);
cout << dst_points.rows <<endl;
cout << dst_points.cols <<endl;
cout << dst_points.type() <<endl;


dstPoint[0] = Point2f(image.cols*0.0,image.rows*0.33);
dstPoint[1] = Point2f(image.cols*0.85,image.rows*0.25);
dstPoint[2] = Point2f(image.cols*0.15,image.rows*0.7);

cout<< "==============dst_point Point2f"<<endl;
cout<< dstPoint[0] << endl;
cout<< dstPoint[1] << endl;
cout<< dstPoint[2] << endl;
cout<< "==============trasform_matrix"<<endl;
Mat transform_matrix = getAffineTransform(srcPoint,dstPoint);
cout << transform_matrix << endl;

cout<< "==============destination"<<endl;
warpAffine(image, image, transform_matrix ,Size(image.cols,image.rows),INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);
cout << "#####destination#####" << endl;
cout << warpAffine << endl;
imshow("WarpAffine image",image);


waitKey(0);
Point2f center;
center = Point2f(image.cols/2 , image.rows/2);
cout << "Center Col"<< endl;
cout << center << endl;
//cout << center[1] << "Center Row"<< endl;

double angle = -90.0 ;
double scale = 0.5;

Mat rotation_matrix = getRotationMatrix2D(center,angle,scale);
warpAffine(image , image , rotation_matrix, Size(image.cols,image.rows));
cout << warpAffine << endl;
imshow("WarpAffine2",image);
waitKey(0);


//return ;
}
```