# Declaring a double array in c++ using brackets or asterisk

Tags: c++, arrays

Having a variable declared like this:

> double *variable;

which I think is pretty the same that writing

> double variable[];

and then some methods working on it;

how is it possible to obtain the length of the array of double? 
What I mean is, how do I know in which position lies the last inizialized / accessed / written element of `variable` ?

Comment: A pointer is not an array.  Also, arrays are dumb as they do not know their own size.  Use `std::vector<double>` or `std::array<double>` instead.

Comment: But `double varialble[]` can actually be a pointer in some situations. So, it depends *where* you're writing it.

Comment: You may find some info [here][1]

hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array) out. If possible use `STL` containers like `std::vector`, to put it simple, it's the fancy C++ way of an array, with `iterators` and functions like `.size()`.

Comment: So writing *variable; or variable[] is completely not the same thing?

Comment: @Paynomindtous I think you're getting confused when seeing the syntax used to access elements (both using `[ ]`), and thus believing that pointers and arrays are the same thing.   There is a big difference if you *declare* a pointer and when you *declare* an array as opposed to *accessing* the elements.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is that:

- `double* variable;` is a pointer meant to be dynamically allocated during execution (via `new` or `malloc` for instance), or may point to a double object (then, it's not an "array").
- `double variable[];` is an array statically allocated (so it's size is defined and fixed during compilation). Note that `double variable[];` is not valid as a declaration. Size of the array must be specified (`double variable[20];` for instance).

**To answer your question:** you cannot determine the number of elements of a `double*` or `double[]` variable, unless you saved it somewhere yourself.

For instance, if you want to pass the double* object to a function, you'll need to pass both pointer and size (number of elements). Function proptotype is then `( double* data, size_t size )`.

```
size_t mySize = 20;
double* data = new double[20];
callFunc( data, mySize );
delete [] data; // need to be deleted because dynamically allocated
```

or:

```
static const size_t mySize = 20;
double data[mySize];
callFunc( data, mySize );
// no need to be deleted because statically allocated
```

As commented by other users, prefer a std::vector which encapsulate a double* pointer and it's number of elements (among other attributes):

```
std::vector<double> data;
data.assign( 20, 0.0 );
callFunc( data );
```

`callfunc` can then access data values and know it's size using `data.size()`.

Note: For char*, convention is to end up the string by a special character (`\0`), so, in this case, you can determine the `size` of the `char` array by finding this special character (that's what `strlen` does). You could do something similar with a double* pointer (like having a NaN to identifiy the last item and then recover the array size), but that would just be a hack and is nor conventional, nor recommended.

Comment: you should also mention that `double* a` is not at all the same as `double a[]` (not only because of size and allocation, but first might be just a pointer). I mean it is mentioned in the comments, but i think it would make your answer a bit nicer.

Comment: "double* variable; is a pointer meant to be dynamically allocated " - in fact it may point to any instance of a `double`

Answer (score 1):

Let me correct you.

```
double* foo;
```

declares a pointer to a double, named foo.

```
double foo[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
```

declares an array of doubles named foo, for which no memory has yet been allocated.  Leftover from C++'s C's roots, is the fact that an array can **decay** to a pointer.  So it is possible to do the following:

```
double foo[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
double bar* = foo[0];  // bar now points to the first element of foo.
```

But this is does not mean that foo and bar are the same thing.  You can use a pointer to iterate over the contents of a c-array (assuming you know the size), , but there are subtle areas where the difference could trip you up (e.g. below).

You could also do something like:

```
double *foo;
// call something that allocates memory for an array and assigned the address of the first element to foo.
```

But in that case you are going to have to keep track of the array size yourself.  That's why in C++, if you are using a statically allocated array, you should prefer std::array, and if you are using a dynamically allocated array, you should prefer std::vector, as these classes will handle the details better than you are likely to.

There is a cute way, which I don't recommend you use, but is an illustration of the differnece between double* and double foo[], which Scott Meyers talks about in "Effective Modern C++":

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arraySize(T (&)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}

double foo[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
constexpr int array_size = arraySize(foo);
```

Will create a c-array with 3 doubles, and initialize the const_expr (it could be a variable, i used const_expr to make it explicit that this is deduced at compile time) array_size to the size of your array.

But avoid all that if you can and use std::array and std::vector when you can.

Comment: "array can degrade to a pointer" -- not true. Arrays *decay* to pointers

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are not arrays.

The code below is an array of size 4:

```
double arr[] {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4};
```

`arr` refers to a block of memory for example:

`0x22fe20 | 0x22fe28 | 0x22fe30 | 0x22fe38 | 0x22fe40`

While the below is pointing to the address of the beginning of `arr`:

```
double *p_arr {arr};
```

> how is it possible to obtain the length of the array of double?

To get the size you can take the size of `arr` and devide it by
the size of the first element:

```
size_t arr_len = (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));
```

Then, we know that the last initialized element is `arr_len - 1`.

---

Instead of manually finding the size ourselves, it's better and safer to use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<double> arr {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4};
std::cout << arr.size();
```