# c++ fill call is creating an error

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error

I'm new to c++, and my program seems to stop working whenever I make a fill call.

```
void go()
{
    int ints[5];
    cout<<"here";
    fill(ints,ints+sizeof(ints),0);
    cout<<"here2";
}
```

The odd thing is, it prints both here1 and here2, and then fails. And if i comment out the fill call, the error no longer occurs. I'm sure it's just something that I'm not doing correctly because I'm new, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *it's just something that I'm not doing correctly*: as an example to not show the body of `fill`, if you think the error is there...

Comment: Take a look at some awesome C++ books, they will help you to avoid such confusions in the future: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @skypjack fill is a c++ method, not mine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the length of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array)

Comment: @user2659185 My fault, I guessed it was something you wrote for exercise. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns the size of the given type in number of `char`s, not the number of elements in the array (i.e. you have the wrong units). Therefore, `ints+sizeof(ints)` is incorrect, it should be `ints + 5`.

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly. for arrays for which I didn't know the size, would it also be sufficient to say    fill(ints,ints+sizeof(ints)/sizeof(int))?

Comment: @user2659185 Better to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which has `begin` and `end` member methods (and a `size` member method).

Comment: Well it does give you the size of the array.  The part that is incorrect is that the size of the array is `sizeof(element_type) * array_size`.  When dealing with arrays and `sizeof()` the correct approach is `sizeof(array_name) / sizeof(array_name[0])`

Comment: @Daniel: C++11 also added [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) free functions that work with arrays too.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well you have used "size" to mean two things here, but you're right, edited to make it clearer.