# What is the correct way to bound while and for loops in C using the sizeof operator, and is this the optimal method?

Tags: c

I have seen some C programs use the sizeof operator to bound loops while iterating over an array. What is the correct method for doing this? I have the example as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    char a[100];
    /* Edited '<=' to '<' as suggested */
    for ( i = 0;i < sizeof a / sizeof *a; ++i)
        a[i] = i;

    for ( i = 0;i < sizeof a / sizeof *a; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sizeof() gives you the (byte) size of a single object of given type, ex: int, bool, etc... this might help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: it needs `<` instead of `<=`. Other than that, your version looks good. Using parentheses after `sizeof` is also advisable.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this use of `sizeof` (except that `sizeof char` is by definition 1 anyway), but your `<=` should be `<`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18078435/887584 This has been answered before, and it mentions that it will not work for pointer types that aren't arrays.

Comment: Do you have some reason for doubting the correctness of the example?  Do you have some uncertainty about the effect of the `sizeof` operator?  Do you think there can be only one correct way of doing what you ask?  I can't help getting the impression that the question you have asked does not express well what you really want to know.

Answer (score 1):

A safer method would be to calculate the size of the array once. Repeating the calculation has the possibility of injecting more defects (such as typos).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    char a[100];
    const unsigned int array_size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    for ( i = 0;i < array_size; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    for ( i = 0;i < array_size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some notes:

1. In `for` loops, the termination is usually "<" (and not "<=") the size because
   indices start at zero.
2. The compiler may already calculate `sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)` as an
   explicit constant once and repeat its value, but I created a
   temporary variable to be explicit.
3. The C and C++ languages are different languages, use your language
   tags appropriately (since you talk about C not C++).
4. I suggest using the term "capacity" for the total number of
   elements, because *size* can mean the number of occupied slots in an
   array (a capacity 10 array may have 4 slots filled, size == 4).

Answer (score -1):

```
// Your way works but I'd change it a little for clarity. (I also fixed the <= issue)

#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_ELEMENTS 100
int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    char a[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    for ( i = 0;i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i)
        a[i] = i;

    for ( i = 0;i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the connection between this and the `sizeof` operator?

Comment: @fanton As I wrote, the OP worked but my way improves clarity. No worries.

Comment: I suspect that the *real* OP question was about the correct usage of `sizeof` operator, not printing the first 100 naturals.

Comment: @fanton Feel free to suspect as you see fit. No worries.