# How to find the length of a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is a java code.

```
for (int j = 0; j < charArray[i].length; j++) {

           System.out.print(charArray[i][j]);

      }
```

Very simple question, how I make the java length property but in c++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the length of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array)

Comment: [What is the equivalent of `array.length()` (used in Java) in C++?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-equivalent-of-array-length-used-in-Java-in-C++), [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810664/995714)

Comment: Consider using one of the C++ container classes, such as `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: As @KeithThompson for C++ you should try to use class types which give you information like size or length. `std::vector` has a [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size), `std::string` has [`size` and `length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) functions

Comment: @JamesAdkison: You should *usually* try to use class types. Sometimes you do need to work with raw arrays (for example if you're implementing `std::vector`!)

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, you should _try_ to avoid raw arrays when possible. I didn't say _**never**_ use them. Same goes for raw pointers and lots of other things. There are no **rules/laws** just the proper application of knowledge and judgment given a set of requirement and constraints. I didn't suggest or imply otherwise.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: I believe we're in violent agreement.

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed we are. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function call by passing the array pointer and you can check if the pointer is null by

```
if (charArray != 0)
```

then you can try this

`sizeof(charArray)/sizeof(charArray[0])`

Comment: I don't get the 0 in charArray[0].

Comment: that means size of the whole array divided by size of a single element

Comment: This works only if `charArray` is actually an array. If you've passed it to a function as a parameter, what you've actually passed is probably a pointer, and its size is unavailable.

Comment: If it's passed to a function as a parameter, then the function should probably look something like `template<size_t N> void funcName(const char (&charArray)[N})`, so it can keep the size information.  ...Although in this case, you could just use `N` for the size, so the point may be moot.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T,unsigned S>
inline unsigned arraysize(const T (&v)[S]) { return S; }
```

The compiler will try to create a function, based on the template, that matches the size of the array. I take no credit for the answer, see the link below, with a lengthier explanation.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/33669/

It doesn't work for a dynamically allocated array, but it gives you a compiler error. Does anything work for a dynamically allocated array?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:
`for(int a=0; charArray[a] != '\0' ; a++);`
This will store the length of charArray in 'a'

Comment: This only works if it's a null terminated string, and will give you the size of the string, not the array. That is, if the string was stored in an array larger than itself, it will just give the size up to where '\0' is. Also, it will result in segmentation faults if the array is not a null terminated string.

Comment: But isn't  it like, all the strings are compulsorily terminated with null character. ???

Comment: And regarding array is concerned, we only need the length of the string. So I guess, it would return length of string until null character is encountered

Comment: Well the question does say 'length of char array', so it doesn't have to be a C style string, and it never asks for anything related to 'strings'. However, if that was indeed what OP meant, then yeah that answer would be correct, although there are library functions for it. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/