# C++ how to push_back an array int[10] to std::vector<int[10]>?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int[60]> v;
int s[60];
v.push_back(s);
```

This code in Visual Studio 2015 community report a compile error:

Error (active)      no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=int [60], _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list

Error   C2664   'void std::vector>::push_back(const int (&)[60])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int (&&)[60]'

Comment: You should use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), raw arrays are finicky and decay to pointers to their first element as soon as you look at them.

Comment: `int[10] s;` is a syntax error you should get a problem on that line too. Also `v.push_back(s)` must occur inside a function

Comment: oh sorry, i made a mistake

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `std::array`, instead:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<array<int, 10>> v;
    array<int, 10> s;
    v.push_back(s);
    return 0;
}
```

But I also have to question the purpose of having a vector containing an array. Whatever is the underlying reason for that, there's likely to be a better way of accomplishing the same goals.

Comment: I generate some int array in one function, each array is an int[60] array. I want to return all these arrays when function end. so I think I need a container like vector<int[60]> v, when I generate a new array, I can just push the new int array into vector.

Comment: Use `std::vector` for the arrays themselves. You obviously know all about `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int t[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    std::vector<int*> v;

    v.push_back(t);

    std::cout << v[0][4] << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

To be more specific in this solution you do not actually store values of array t into vector v you just store pointer to array (and to be even more specific to first element of array)

Comment: I think your method and the std::array<int, 60> all meet my request. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure are you saying initialize a vector from an array, if yes here is a way to do it using vector's constructor:

```
int s[] = {1,2,3,4};
vector<int> v (s,  s + sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]));
```

Comment: sizeof(s) - this can be tricky as you can use int s[] as function parameter and it will be converted to int* s and you will get sizeof(int*)

Comment: You are right, base on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array       I was assuming he is using C style array as he stated at OP

Comment: no, I need collect lots of array with a container, such as vector. each array is a int[60].