# Calculation of Array size using sizeof()

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

Excerpt from TopCoder [article](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/power-up-c-with-the-standard-template-library-part-1/#summary):

> The expression `sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])` returns the size of the array `data`, but only in **a few cases**, so don’t use it anywhere except in such constructions.(C programmers will agree with me!)

To get array size, I've been using this expression `sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])` all the time for **all primitive types**.

Does anyone know about any such case in which the above expression **should not** be used?

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::array` and you won't care about when that won't work.

Comment: yeah, I use them in C++. But many times, I code in C as well, where I use this expression. Is this problem language specific?

Comment: I think it isnt typesafe

Comment: If you need to use raw arrays (C++ or C), you should keep and pass with it the size of the array as an additional parameter.

Comment: Maybe [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array) would be informative as to why the author makes that blanket assessment.

Comment: You can also read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array) with a thorough answer.

Comment: @MikelF (from the revision history): C++ that looks like C is still C++, and this question is about C++. Transforming it into a C question would also invalidate [Dietmar Kühl's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41385937/3233393).

Comment: Actually on-topic: "a few cases" is wonderfully unhelpful, and also wrong within this sentence -- if `data` **is** an array, `sizeof/sizeof` will *always* work.

Comment: @Quentin I based my suggestion in part on the OPs comment about how he uses STL containers in C++, but uses the mentioned expression in C.

Comment: @MikelF I see what you mean. I'm not sure how to fix this Q&A now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `data` were declared like so:

```
int *data;
```

And then space for it allocated like so:

```
data = malloc( NUM_ELEMENTS * sizeof(int) );
```

Then your technique will not work, because `sizeof(data)` is the size of a *pointer*, not the content of the array.

Answer (score 4):

The `sizeof` approach compiles but doesn't work when giving it a pointer or an array of indeterminate size. Just use the proper C++ approach:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(T(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Using `size()` on an array works correctly. It will be a compile-time error to use it in a case where it is not applicable, e.g., on a pointer.

Comment: Or even easier since `c++11` `std::extent<decltype(array)>::value`

Comment: Thanks.. What is this expression called `T(&)[N]` i.e. `&` inside brackets as argument? Seeing it first time. What term I should google, any hints?

Comment: @SebTu: somehow I think `size(array)` is expressing more clearly what it intended and is easier to type than `std::extent<decltype(array)>::value`.

Comment: @SauraSaha: that's just a reference to an array type. The array type is `T[N]`. Simply writing `T[N]&` is illegal and `T&[N]` would be an array of references (which is also illegal). Essentially the reference (or pointer) goes where the name goes but it needs appropriate parenthesis to disambiguate what is meant. Hence `T(&)[N]`. If it had a name which isn't needed for the function it would be `T (&array)[N]`.

Comment: @SauravSahu take a look at the [clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Helped me a lot many times. Especially do not forget to consider the  third rule : 3. Always resolve anything in parenthesis first!

Answer (score 0):

The sizeof technique work correction for static array, it will not have any issue. As mentioned in the above for dynamic array and pointer data it will not work correctly.