# How does std::end work on native arrays

Tags: c++, c++11

In Modern C++, we can use std::end on native arrays. I wanted to ask how does this work to understand the performance considerations for this.

Comment: It works [like this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end)

Comment: See also Motti's answer [to this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array called `a` with size `N`, then `std::end(a)` means the same thing as `a + N`. It doesn't need to do any run-time work to find the size of the array, because the size is known at compile time.

Note that `std::end` won't work on a pointer. It will only work on an array that has not been decayed to a pointer, so the size information is statically present at the call site.