# Assiging value to map from anonymous namespace throw std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, stdmap

Below is code through error as std::bad_alloc. I am getting error on
line **obj_[key[i]] = value[i];** . please help me to fix it .

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<map>
  using namespace std;

 namespace {
         const std::string key1 = "s1";
         const std::string key2 = "s2";

         const std::string value1 = "v1";
         const std::string value2= "v2";
 }

 int main()
 {

         std::string key[3] = {
                 key1, key2};
          std::string value[3] = {
                  value1,value2 };
         std::map<std::string,std::string> obj_;

         for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(key); ++i) { // here its thow std::bad_alloc
                 obj_[key[i]] = value[i];
            }
}
```

Comment: Note that `key` and `value` hold 3 elements each but you only initialize two of them. You may be confused by c strings which needs an extra element to store a null terminator.

Comment: `sizeof(key)` isn't 3, it's `sizeof(std::string) * 3`.

Comment: What does this say: `std::cout << sizeof(key) << "\n";`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i change as per your suggestion but still same result. terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Prefer `std::array` and its `size` member function.

Comment: @josp I'm not sure what you tried, but changing `i < sizeof(key)` to `i < 3` let me run your example just fine. The map contains three pairs, the third being `{"", ""}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(key)` is the size of the array in **bytes**. It's not the amount of elements.

Instead you should be using `std::extent_v<decltype(key)>`. (Requires `#include <type_traits>`.)

Pre-C++17 alternative: `std::extent<decltype(key)>::value`. (Requires `#include <type_traits>` as well.)

If that's too fancy for your taste, there's a poor man's alternative: `sizeof(key)/sizeof(key[0])`.

Or just hardcode the `3`.

Comment: can you please give example code which give size using ur below suggestion.
Instead you should be using std::extent_v<decltype(key)>. (Requires #include <type_traits>.)

Comment: @josp You just replace `sizeof(key)` with `std::extent_v<decltype(key)>`. And also add `#include <type_traits>` on top of the file.

Comment: Below error is throw :
mapex.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
mapex.cc:23:25: error: ‘extent_v’ is not a member of ‘std’
  for (size_t i = 0; i < std::extent_v<decltype(key)> ; ++i) {
                         ^
mapex.cc:23:39: error: expected primary-expression before ‘decltype’
  for (size_t i = 0; i < std::extent_v<decltype(key)> ; ++i) {

Comment: compile with c++ -std=c++11 mapex.cc

Comment: @josp It requires C++17. Try with `-std=c++17`. If the flag doesn't work, it means that your compiler is too old. Update it, or try the other two options.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(key)` = 96 (on os 64bit). To get the size of the array you have to divide this number by `sizeof(std::string)` (which is 32 (on os 64bit)):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(key) / sizeof(std::string); ++i) {
     obj_[key[i]] = value[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `sizeof(key)` here:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i <  sizeof(key); ++i) { // here its thow std::bad_alloc
        obj_[key[i]] = value[i];
    }
```

**EDIT 21.08.2018**
use `(sizeof(key)/sizeof(*key))` instead:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i <  (sizeof(key)/sizeof(*key)); ++i) { // here its thow std::bad_alloc
        obj_[key[i]] = value[i];
    }
```

Comment: Nope. It'll give you the length of the first string, not the array.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `sizeof()` it returns the [size in bytes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) of the object, not the number of elements as you seem to be expecting. Additionally when using the operator `[]` you access directly the encapsulated data inside the array, with [no bound check](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), this combination is probably your error source. [You can do the math](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4108340/10193803) and figure out how many elements you have.

Since you previously know your array size, you can use an `std::array` instead.

```
std::array<std::string,3> key = {key1, key2, ""}; //you only used two values in your code
for (size_t i = 0; i < key.size(); ++i) {
  //your instructions
}
```

It is a bit odd that even explicitly setting your array's size, you still need to inquire about its size in the loop. Supposing this is an unintended feature of your problem statement, and you don't know its size in advance, I would recommend you to use an std::vector instead.

Comment: `key.size()` and `key.length()` wouldn't compile. `key` is an array.

Comment: You're right, I missed that. The answer is edited, it should be fine now.