# Why can't I access the size of this C++ array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, deque

I am new to C++, and I am trying to write a function to solve  [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/deque-stl/problem) challenge. The code I have looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque> 
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void printKMax(int arr[], int n, int k){
    deque<int> subarray;
    int i = arr.size();
    int maxValues[n];

    while(i >= 0) { 
        while (subarray.size() < n) {
            subarray.push_back(arr[i]);
            arr.pop();
            --i;
        }
        maxValues.push(max_element(begin(subarray), end(subarray)));
        subarray.pop_front();
    }

    for (array<int>::iterator it=maxValues.begin(); it!=maxValues.end(); 
it++) { 
        cout << maxValues[*it] << " ";
    }

}

int main(){

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t>0) {
        int n,k;
        cin >> n >> k;
        int i;
        int arr[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin >> arr[i];
        printKMax(arr, n, k);
        t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is throwing, among other things, an error saying:

> "request for member ‘size’ in ‘arr’, which is of non-class type
>   ‘int*’   int i = arr.size();"

Can someone please help me understand what this means? Am I trying to reference something from outside of the class, so that I need to use a pointer? Is it a problem with the way the array is declared?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a `std::vector` or `std::array` to do that. Raw arrays don not have any class member functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the length of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C-style array isn't an object and you can't call `size` on it. It degenerates to nothing more than a pointer, and if you pass it here

```
void printKMax(int arr[], int n, int k){
```

Then this function doesn't even know the size. To solve the problem, you need to pass the size separately, as another parameter. Alternatively, you could just use a data structure such as `std::vector` instead, I would recommend this over using a plain array in this situation. Instead of `int arr[n];` you would have `std::vector<int> arr;`. You can then query the [size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) of the `std::vector` in your `printKMax` function. Accessing the vector uses the same syntax as accessing an array, and filling the vector works similar to how you're doing it now, with `cin >> arr`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this statement to get length of array

`int length = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));`

Comment: are u sure about this? It didn't work