# Can someone tell me why I am unable to find the length of array using sizeof() function here?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof, function-call

When I changed the code to include an argument for size, the code worked correctly. But I cannot understand the error it is showing when I'm calculating length of array using sizeof() ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display(int arr[]){
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int* ptr=arr;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cout << i << " : " << *ptr << endl;
        ptr++;
    }
} 

int main(){
    int arr[9] = {2,5,3,8,5,4,6,1,7};
    display(arr);   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should show some code. You probably tried passing a C array into a function directly, which is not possible in C++.

Comment: Please post code directly, not through pictures.

Comment: Probably due to decay to a pointer type, but without any code it's impossible to say.

Comment: Don't attach images of code. Paste code.

Comment: Aside: In C++, you have `std::vector<int>`, which is a *much better* model of "a variable number of elements" than `int[]`

Comment: A good dupe target should mention passing the array by reference and deducing the size. Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18078435).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the length of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array)

Comment: @nwp: I can't close to that duplicate since I've already used my close vote.

Comment: Minor nit: `sizeof` is an **operator**, not a **function**.

Answer (score 4):

```
void display(int arr[], int n)
```

This is a lie, but that's not your fault.

During compilation it is automatically re-written to:

```
void display(int* arr, int n)
```

That is, although *arrays are not pointers*, silly old C features can make us think that they are! It is impossible to pass an array by value so you're really just passing a pointer to the first element.

As such, you're doing `sizeof(int*)`.

Instead, I suggest using `sizeof(*arr) * n`, or pass a *reference* to the array:

```
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
void display(const int (&arr)[N])
{
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << i << " : " << arr[i] << '\n';
} 

int main(){
    int arr[9] = {2,5,3,8,5,4,6,1,7};
    display(arr);
}
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11aca0e62483f3b4))

… or rewrite your function to take an iterator pair instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename It>
void display(const It begin, const It end)
{
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for (It it = begin; it != end; ++it)
        std::cout << i++ << " : " << *it << '\n';
} 

int main(){
    int arr[9] = {2,5,3,8,5,4,6,1,7};
    display(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
}
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ce4092f494b9343))

Comment: You also could consider `template <std::size_t N> void display(int arr[N]);`

Comment: @JulianH That has the same problem (the `N` is completely unused) and is thus a misleading piece of code. `template <std::size_t N> void display(const int (&arr)[N])` works though

Comment: −1. Yet another duplicate answer to the same question.