# What is the better way of getting a length of a C-Style Array?

Tags: c++, c++11

These days I am reading the C++ primer. The book says that, to get the length of a C-Style array, you can use the function std::begin and std::end to get two pointers and subtract them . However, I knew that I can also use `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` if `a` is a C-Style array. So which way is better, or they just have little differences?

Comment: This has been discussed in detail in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array)

Comment: The best way to get the size is to not throw it away in the first place. `const count = 5; int array[count];`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to go nowadays (C++17 and above) is [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size):

```
#include <iterator>
...
int arr[5];
static_assert(std::size(arr) == 5);
```

If you don't have access to C++17, it's pretty easy to roll your own too:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size(const T (&arr)[N]) { return N; }
```

---

Even better, just use `std::array`, and use it's size member:

```
std::array<int, 5> arr;
static_assert(arr.size() == 5);
```

Comment: ...and `std::array` is the bestest of them all. ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, absolutely

Answer (score 2):

The method with `std::begin` and `std::end` is a better one because it is safer. So is `std::size`.

If you by mistake use the `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` method on a pointer instead of an array, the compiler will likely tell you nothing, and you will get a meaningless result. The other methods will result in a compilation error, and you will know you are trying to do something wrong.

One drawback of the `std::begin` and `std::end` method is that the result is not a constant expression. The result of `std::size` is, so this should be a preferred method of getting the size of a C-style array.

Comment: Can the difference between `std::begin` and `std::end` be computed at compile time? Otherwise, there may be a runtime overhead to calculate the size.

Comment: @TrickorTreat It can be though there's no guarantee. https://godbolt.org/z/ZPzjfG