# How can I know in C++ how many elements an array contains?

Tags: c++, arrays

For example, I have an array with 3 elements

```
int array [] = {1, 4, 66};
```

How can I know how many elements `array` contains?

Comment: In `c++17` you have [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array

Comment: The whole answer is in Below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` and call the `.size()` member function. Forget that C-style arrays exist and don't ever use them.

Answer (score 5):

Do this with:

```
std::size(myarray);
```

[`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is in `<iterator>`.

---

Some sources will tell you to use a "trick" like `sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(myarray[0])`. But this is error-prone. The name of an array decays really easily to a pointer, for which this "trick" gives the wrong result. `std::size` will either work, or break the build.

Plus, when you switch from C arrays to `std::array`, *it'll still work*!

Comment: In case they don't have c++17 `template <typename T, std::size_t N> std::size_t size(const T(&)[N]) { return N; }`

Comment: Yep like it says on the linked article ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(int)`.

But you really should start using `std::array`, which does the same thing as your array and is safer. And comes with a `size()` method.