# How can I get the length of an array that was passed to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference, sizeof, function-definition

Given the following function:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T* ar)
{
    std::cout << sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]) << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        std::cout << ar[i] << " ";
}
```

And following array:

```
int ar[] = { 5, 1, 6, 8, 9, 3 };
foo(ar);
```

I expected the program to print '6' and then the contents of the array. But for some reason, `sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0])` evaluates to 1 (since both `sizeof(ar)` and `sizeof(ar[0])` evaluate to '4'), but the print works fine (meaning passed array does contain all 6 elements).

This only happens to arrays passed to functions (I tried evaluating length in main(), where array was declared and it worked fine). How can I get the length of an array inside a function?

Comment: You cannot get the length through a pointer. That's why using `std::vector` is the preferred way of passing arrays

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array?rq=1

Comment: @UnholySheep, so if I have to work with arrays only way would be to pass the length to the function as well?

Comment: The array `ar` decays to a pointer when passed to a function, so `ar` in `foo` is just a pointer

Comment: You should pass an `array_view`, or pass array by reference, or pass size explicitly. And never ever use something like `sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0])` to figure out size of the array, use `::std::size` instead.

Comment: apparantly `void foo(T &ar)` works. `sizeof(ar)` returns 24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare the parameter as having a referenced type.

For example

```
template<class T>
void foo( const T &ar )
{
    size_t n = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]);
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << ar[i] << " ";
}
```

Or you may use the following declaration

```
template<class T, size_t N>
void foo( const T ( &ar )[N] )
{
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << ar[i] << " ";
}
```

Otherwise the function deals with a pointer. In this case you need specify a second parameter that denotes the length of the array like

```
template<class T>
void foo( const T* ar, size_t n )
{
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << ar[i] << " ";
}
```

As the passed array is not being changed in the function then the corresponding parameter should have the qualifier `const`.

Pay attention to that in the C++ 17 Standard there is introduced standard function `std::size` declared in the header `<iterator>` that can be used 
instead of the expression `sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0])`

So you could write for example in the first shown function

```
size_t n = std::size(ar)`;
```

Comment: I think I will go with the first one, `void foo( const T &ar )`, but in this case type T becomes `array`. Is there any way to get the type of the element of that array?

Comment: @Ach113 You can include the header <type_traits> and use something like typename std::remove_extent_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype( ar )>> x;

Comment: @Ach113 You can this long record make shorter by using an alias declaration. For example using Type = typename std::remove_extent_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype( ar )>>;        
  Type x = 10;

Comment: thing is, I want to create an object of that type `SomeObject<T>`. I need to pass a datatype like `int` to it. But if T becomes an array, what could I do in this case?

Comment: @Ach113 You can declare the function like  template<class T>
void foo( const T &ar, typename std::remove_extent_t<T> x );

Comment: I think the last piece of code should have constexpr : `constexpr size_t N = std::size(ar)`;`