# How can I get the number of elements in an already array declare by using size function not (sizeof)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, size

How can I get the number of elements in an already declared array by using the `size()` function, not `sizeof()`?

I did that by using the `sizeof()`, `begin()`, and `end()` functions, but how about the `size()` function??

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nums[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 50};
    
    // Method 1
    cout << sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]) << "\n";
    
    // Method 2
    cout << end(nums) - begin(nums) << "\n";
    
    // Method 3
    // ???

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See the c++17 part of this answer on how to use std::size(): [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61670385/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61670385/487892)

Comment: `auto nums_size = std::size(num);`

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)  cppreference contains an example.

Comment: A user has transcribed your code for you, from the image you presented. That was nice of them, but do note that code needs to be shared here in _text format_, and it's **your** responsibility to do that. Future images of code instead of text will likely result in your question(s) being closed for lacking a [mcve].

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428224/whats-with-downvoting-perfectly-understandable-questions-and-viable-answers)

Comment: I agree, code should be posted as text, not as an image. [MikeCAT's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78042841/#comment137584495_78042841) above has a link explaining in more detail why images should not be used for code.

Answer (score 1):

C++17 and later has a [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) function in the `<iterator>` header (and various others), e.g.:

```cpp
#include <iterator>

std::cout << std::size(nums) << "\n";
```

C++20 adds the [`std::ssize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) function, eg:

```cpp
std::cout << std::ssize(nums) << "\n";
```

And just for good measure, another approach would be to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a C-style array, and then you can use its [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) method, eg:

```cpp
#include <array>

std::array<int, 6> nums{10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 50};    

std::cout << nums.size() << "\n";
```

Comment: What's the difference between `std::size` and `std::ssize`?

Comment: @Elikill58 `std::size()` returns an *unsigned* integer type, whereas `std::ssize()` returns a *signed* integer type (hence the extra `s` in its name)

Answer (score 0):

Or use a template function with a non-type template parameter to deduce the array's size yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto get_size(T(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}

int main()
{
    int nums[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 50};
    std::cout<<"size: "<< get_size(nums) <<'\n';  // size: 6
}
```